# Generate Cell Array of Multiple Rows and Columns From Text File

Tags: matlab, text-processing, cell-array

I have a text file formatted like this:

```
ab cd ef gh ij
ab cd ef gh ij
ab cd ef gh ij
```

How can I import this data into Matlab so that it is stored as a `cell array` that is equivalent to this 3x5 `cell array`:

```
C = {
    ['ab'], ['cd'], ['ef'], ['gh'], ['ij'];
    ['ab'], ['cd'], ['ef'], ['gh'], ['ij'];
    ['ab'], ['cd'], ['ef'], ['gh'], ['ij'];
    };
```

I can modify the text file to contain some sort of "end-of-line" indicator if needed.  I tried using `textscan`, but can't figure out how to get it to format the variable as described.

EDIT: Changed the accepted answer; I like the handling of potentially missing data points in Divakar's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
c1 = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x),importdata(textfile_path),'un',0);
C = vertcat(c1{:})
```

This basically reads the text data into a cell array which is run through `strsplit` to split the data into cells and rest is just re-arranging the data to get the desired output.

Instead of strsplit, you can use `regexp` there -

```
c1 = regexp(importdata(textfile_path),'\s','split'); %// As suggested by Luis!
```

---

### Bonus stuff

Let's suppose you have an "irregular" shaped text file i.e. to say, some data is missing along the columns at *the trailing positions*, something like this -

```
ab cd ef gh ij
ab ry mf pp
ab ui rt ko bw
```

In that case, you can use a modified version of the earlier code -

```
c1 = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x),importdata(textfile_path),'un',0);
lens = cellfun('length',c1);

C = cell(max(lens),numel(c1));
C(bsxfun(@le,[1:max(lens)]',lens')) = [c1{:}];
C = C'
```

The output stays committed to that 2D structure, keeping empty cells for the empty places -

```
C = 
    'ab'    'cd'    'ef'    'gh'    'ij'
    'ab'    'ry'    'mf'    'pp'      []
    'ab'    'ui'    'rt'    'ko'    'bw'
```

Comment: One of these days I'll learn `importdata`.  Using `fopen` and `fclose` gets really old.

Comment: @chappjc It's short and simple, and best thing, you dont need to mess with delimiters.

Comment: But for people living in the past, like my self :), the `printf`-like format specifiers come so naturally.

Comment: +1 No need for `cellfun`. `regexp` handles cell arrays. So you can use `c1 = regexp(importdata(textfile_path),'\s','split');`

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to use `textscan`.

1. Horizontally concatenate the output of `textscan` via a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html):

   ```
   fid = fopen('testdat.dat');
   C = textscan(fid,'%s %s %s %s %s'); fclose(fid);
   C = [C{:}]
   ```

   Looks like this:

   ```
   >> C = [C{:}]
   C = 
       'ab'    'cd'    'ef'    'gh'    'ij'
       'ab'    'cd'    'ef'    'gh'    'ij'
       'ab'    'cd'    'ef'    'gh'    'ij'
   ```
2. Collect output via `textscan`'s `'CollectOutput'` option:

   ```
   >> C = textscan(fid,'%s %s %s %s %s','CollectOutput',true),  fclose(fid);
   C = 
       {3x5 cell}
   >> C = C{1}
   C = 
       'ab'    'cd'    'ef'    'gh'    'ij'
       'ab'    'cd'    'ef'    'gh'    'ij'
       'ab'    'cd'    'ef'    'gh'    'ij'
   ```